# Return rows if they don't have entry in second table too?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm joining 2 tables(table A and table B), where I expect it to return matching results from tableB. also, if no matching results available return empty.

eg:

```
Select a.ID,a.Code,b.result 
from Table A as a
LEFT JOIN table B as b on a.ID=b.codeid
Where a.Timestamp<'2019-07-01' and b.xx=xx
```

Currently I get:

Sample data I get:

```
ID  Code Result
1   AS01 Pass
2   BXY  Fail
....
```

I prefer to get

```
 ID   Code Result
 1    AS01 Pass
 2    BXY  Fail
 .... 
 1000 DCY
```

In above, if particular ID (eg: 1000) not have any entry in table B I'm not getting anything.

But I want to return empty Result column for that 1000 Id. How to do that?

Comment: Is this the complete query or do you have a `where` clause too?

Comment: what results you are getting now? some sample input and output data would help. Your query seems Ok.

Comment: Your query seems fine. If your  `where` clause had conditions regarding the `b` table then your problem would be explainable.

Comment: @juergend Yes I have where clause for table B. How can I achieve my prefered result with same where clause

Comment: @mkRabbani I added sample data and the result i prefer to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` condition filtering on `tableB` turns your `left join` into an `inner join`. Put that condition directly into the `join`:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Code, b.result 
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.codeid
                  AND B.xx = xx
WHERE a.Timestamp < '2019-07-01'
```